# Detect client disconnection without sending ANY data to the server

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, server, client

I'm trying to detect whether client disconnected from the server.

**ONLY the server is sending information to the client.

Client is just a listener, it gets information.**

I can't make client a 'server' and server a 'client' because there will be like 10 clients which connect to server and
**server sends information to them but not constantly**. Only when a user clicks the button.
So I find this task really hard and I can't really find anything out there because my case is I think unusual.
I've tried with `socket.recv(1024)` but as I said there is no continuous communication between client and the server. 
Server thread code (It inherits from QObject because I'm using PyQt 5):

```py
class ServerThread(QObject):

    def __init__(self):
        print("(DEBUG) WATEK PROGRAMU URUCHOMIONY")
        QObject.__init__(self)

    def receive_msg(self, client_soc):
        try:
            message_header = client_soc.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)

            if not len(message_header):
                return False

            message_length = int(message_header.decode("utf-8"))
            return {"header": message_header, "data": client_soc.recv(message_length)}
        except:
            return False

    def thread_runner(self):
        global client_socket
        global client_address
        global sockets_list
        global server_soc

        while True:
            read_sockets, _, exception_sockets = select.select(sockets_list, [], sockets_list)

            for notified_socket in read_sockets:
                if notified_socket == server_soc:
                    client_socket, client_address = server_soc.accept()

                    connected_clients.append(client_socket)

                    clients[client_socket] = client_address

                    print(
                        f"(DEBUG) Accepted new connection from {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]}")
                else:
                    msg = self.receive_msg(notified_socket)
                    if not msg:
                        print(
                            f"(DEBUG) Closed connection from {notified_socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())}")
                        sockets_list.remove(notified_socket)
                        del clients[notified_socket]

            for notified_socket in exception_sockets:
                sockets_list.remove(notified_socket)
                del clients[notified_socket]
```

Client code:

```py
while True:
    try:
        msg_header = client_soc.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
        msg_length = int(msg_header.decode('utf-8'))
        msg = client_soc.recv(msg_length).decode('utf-8')
        print(msg)

        if LINK_SIG in msg:
            msg_list = msg.split("|<->|")
            link = msg_list[1]
            print(f"(DEBUG) {LINK_SIG} SIGNAL RECEIVED: {link}")
            link_received(link)

        if msg == LOCK_PC:
            print(f"(DEBUG) {LOCK_PC} SIGNAL RECEIVED")
            lock_pc(True)
        elif msg == BLOCK_KEYBOARD:
            print(f"(DEBUG) {BLOCK_KEYBOARD} SIGNAL RECEIVED")
            blocker = KeyboardBlocker(True)
            blocker.start()
        elif msg == BLOCK_MOUSE:
            print(f"(DEBUG) {BLOCK_MOUSE} SIGNAL RECEIVED")
            block_mouse(True)

        if msg == UNBLOCK_KEYBOARD:
            print(f"(DEBUG) {UNBLOCK_KEYBOARD} SIGNAL RECEIVED")
            blocker = KeyboardBlocker(False)
            blocker.start()
        elif msg == UNBLOCK_MOUSE:
            print(f"(DEBUG) {UNBLOCK_MOUSE} SIGNAL RECEIVED")
            block_mouse(False)

    except IOError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EAGAIN and e.errno != errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
            print("(ERROR) Reading error!", str(e))
            sys_exit()

    except Exception as e:
        print("(ERROR) General error!", str(e))
        sys_exit()
```

I really need help with this and is it even possible? Do I have to refactor my code for it to work? What should I do?

Comment: Can you explain why specifically you don't want any type of data sent to the server? How do you expect the server to know which client to send it to?

Even if it's just for the purpose of obtaining a single byte to signify a request, sending that alone can be very helpful if not critical.

Comment: The server is sending the same information to every client. I'm making some kind of remote controller. One user is the server (controller) and sends information to other users (clients, which connect to the server). The information is the same for every connected client.

Comment: If you close the connection immediately after each message is sent, you could just reopen them when needed. For example `client_socket, client_address = server_soc.accept()` waits for a connection. When that connection is established, that is a signal that the client sent a connection request with `client_soc.connect((host, port))` after that the client, can receive the header info with `client_soc.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)` and the server can send it to the `client_socket` that it obtained with the `accept()` method. Then the data can be received and sent and the connection closed. Rinse and repeat

Comment: Note that a new connection will have to be created and established after each connection with this method. Additionally, the server does not need to know the clients address since it obtains it with `accept()`. Does that make sense? If not I can create a simple example.

Comment: I mean, I'm not closing connection after each message is sent. The client just connects and stays connected forever until user closes the client app and that is what I want to detect as then the client is disconnecting.

Comment: You need only to read from the client connection. When the client closes it, `recv()` will return zero.